# Why does it give an error 'searchInput' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to search for people. An array of data is stored in the redux store. I'm trying to perform a search, but an error occurs.

`Cannot read property 'searchInput' of undefined`

What could be the problem?

```
searchHandler(){
  console.log('findUser', this.searchInput.value);
  this.props.onFindPeople(this.searchInput.value)
}
```

I add an example [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/q7oxkkpqoj)

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to post all the relevant code, i.e. component, storeToProps, reducer, etc.

Comment: @SebastianRothbucher he has it posted in the `code` link

Comment: @max are you doing binding of searchHandler in constructor?

Comment: the function was decided by the, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not binding the function. You need to bind it in constructor like below. Binding is required in order to access this and access state, props and modifying the state.

Please note you need to bind it only in constructor not anywhere else in the component

```
 constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.searchHandler = this.searchHandler.bind(this);
 }

 searchHandler(){
     console.log('findUser', this.searchInput.value);
     this.props.onFindPeople(this.searchInput.value);
 }
```

Or you can also use arrow function as Sagiv mentioned in his answer.

Comment: thanks, but there is an easy way to perform searches not only by name, but by other parameters? this is another matter

Comment: Yes. If you are looking for more details then you can put that as a separate question about the issue

Answer (score 2):

You lost the context of `this` to the event handler.
You can either use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (that uses a lexical context for `this`):

```
  searchHandler = () => {
    console.log("findUser", this.searchInput.value);
    this.props.onFindPeople(this.searchInput.value);
  }
```

Or [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) it to the class like this:

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.searchHandler = this.searchHandler.bind(this);
  }
```

We do it in the `constructor` because it will run only once.

Comment: I checked the OP's snippet, this is the problem and arrow function or `bind` fixes it

Comment: you're the best, thank you! And it is possible still a question?

Comment: I want to click on the user, display more information about him on the right. I tried to withdraw, but all are output at once? Can you help me?

Comment: I think its better to close this question (if you think you got a valid answer) and open a new one as its not related to the same issue here and may confuse future readers. you can post a link to the new one as a comment and i'll try to answer it (or someone else)

Comment: I can ask the next question in 90 minutes, unfortunately.

Comment: @max what? didn't know there is a limit here